# Cross-Validation PCA in selecting number of PCA components

Tags: cross-validation, pca

If I have 3 datasets and make comparison between them and after calculation of PCA components for each dataset. For instance, If D1 gave us 7 pc components , D2 gave 5pcs and D3 gave 4 pcs . How can I combine these differences to select specific unique number of pcs for the the three datasets? Which mathematical rule can be used ? I applied first the measurement of the crossvalidation using ckf and reduction the prediction error to identify each dataset components.